# How do you convert a table with mixed data types to a single data type?

Tags: matlab

I have a table in defined in Matlab that is a mixture of strings and integers, i.e.

```
    A             B         C         D         D
    ----------    ---       ---       ---       ---
    1.0002e+05    '2'       '2'       '1'       '2'   
    1.0002e+05    '2'       '1'       '2'       '2'   
    1.0002e+05    '2'       '2'       '1'       '1'   
    1.0003e+05    '2'       '2'       '2'       '1'   
    1.0003e+05    '2'       '2'       '3'       '1'
```

Thanks to some data cleansing I know that the only thing let is integer data. As such, how can I apply `str2num` to the table so that everything is updated at once?

Comment: Have you looked at [varfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html)?

Comment: @excaza I did, but I couldn't figure out quite how to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach utilizing [dynamic field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/), which work for tables as well.

Assuming your table `T` is set up as above:

```
myvarnames = T.Properties.VariableNames;
for ii = 1:length(myvarnames)
    if iscell(T.(myvarnames{ii}))
        % If your table variable contains strings then we will have a cell
        % array. If it's numeric data it will just be in a numeric array
        T.(myvarnames{ii}) = str2double(T.(myvarnames{ii}));
    end
end
```

We can also use [`varfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html) (e.g. `T = varfun(@str2double, T)`) but in this case it will error out because not all of the variables are strings. I'm assuming this is the case but the error message is pretty cryptic (`MATLAB:table:RowDimensionMismatch`). You can catch this with a [`try/catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) block but you run the risk of passing on an actual dimension mismatch, which I don't like. You can also utilize the [`InputVariables` name-value pair](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html#input_argument_namevalue_inputvariables) if you know explicitly which variables you want to pass.

`varfun` also annoyingly renames the variables that are passed. Granted, it only takes a one liner to fix it but it's still annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there might be a cleaner way of doing this, but assuming that the table is named `data`,

```
% Convert the data new table that contains the numeric data
conversion = array2table(cellfun(@str2num, table2cell(data(:, 2:end))));

% Copy the column names over
conversion.Properties.VariableNames = data.Properties.VariableNames(2:end);

% Delete the old columns
data(:, 2:end) = [];

% Concatenate the new table
data = [data conversion];
```

Comment: I see table as a way to represent data in a nice way. Mainly because you can easily run into troubles like this one. The recommendation is that you use another approach (maybe using cells?) and only use tables for graphical representation. You may however have good reasons to do as you do, so this is not intended as critizism. Still as a Java programmer at daytime I do not see this approach as "unclean" or anything like this. I guess this is fairly standard when working with User defined types (meant as "written in Matlab" and not fundamental types such as double, int8, ...).

Comment: @patrik there doesn't seem to be much practical difference between the `table` and `structure` data types